# Git track untracked files without adding to commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset, git-stage, git-untracked

I ran the command "git reset", but my unstaged changes were put into folders instead. I get something like the following after running git status:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1
    modified:   file2
    modified:   file3
    modified:   file4
    modified:   file5

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    folder1
    folder2
    folder3
    folder4
```

Each of the folders contains multiple files which I modified, but were for some reason grouped into these folders.

I need to separate these changes into multiple pull requests, so "git commit -a" won't do.

The best solution I see is to "git add -all", copy the "git status", and "git reset" again, but that seems like a lot of effort.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git only tracks files (not folders / directories).

However, for optimization purposes, `git status` *reports* untracked files within a sub-directory / folder using an abbreviated format, if possible.

To de-abbreviate, use `git status -uall` (that's `-u` + `all`, as in "show me all the files, not a shortened list").  You can also write `-uno` meaning show *no* files, or just `-u` which means `-uall` anyway.  The default is `-unormal`, which is the normal abbreviated version.

You can add any individual file, e.g.:

```
git add folder1/foo.txt
```

and now that file is tracked, and `git status` can no longer abbreviate: it must list all still-untracked files in `folder1/` one at a time, since `folder1/foo.txt` is tracked.

Comment: thanks, worked for me edit: -uno didn't, but just -u did

Comment: @user2605633: oops, braino, it's `-uall`! Will fix answer.